# ElementNotInteractableException: element not interactable error while trying to search for stock on www.finanzen.net using Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

Im trying to search for stock on www.finanzen.net using selenium but always get

ElementNotInteractableException: element not interactable

```
from selenium import webdriver

import time

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
prefs = {"profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications" : 2}
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)
chrome_options.add_argument("start-maximized")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options, executable_path=r'F:\chromedriver.exe')

driver.get('https://www.finanzen.net/')
time.sleep(5)
cookie_banner_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@onclick='cookieBannerOverlayClick();']")
cookie_banner_button.click()

search_field = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@class='search-input']")


#search_field.click()
search_field.send_keys('bmw')
search_field.submit()
time.sleep(5)
driver.quit()
```

HTML:

[image: html-code of element]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The xpath that you have used are pointing to two elements and first element on which it is pointing is not interactable due to which you are getting the exception.
Have found the correct xpath for the element, please refer to the code below:

```
from selenium import webdriver

import time

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
prefs = {"profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications" : 2}
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)
chrome_options.add_argument("start-maximized")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options, 
executable_path=r'F:\chromedriver.exe')

driver.get('https://www.finanzen.net/')
time.sleep(5)
cookie_banner_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@onclick='cookieBannerOverlayClick();']")
cookie_banner_button.click()

search_field = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='shadow']//input[@class='search-input']")
search_field.send_keys('bmw')
search_field.submit()
time.sleep(5)
driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 1):

To search for stock on www.finanzen.net you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  driver.get('https://www.finanzen.net/')
  submit_button = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "form[name='mmssearch'] div.search-group>input.search-input[name='_search']")))
  submit_button.send_keys('bmw')
  submit_button.submit()
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  driver.get('https://www.finanzen.net/')
  submit_button = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//form[@name='mmssearch']//div[@class='search-group']/input[@class='search-input' and @name='_search']")))
  submit_button.send_keys('bmw')
  submit_button.submit()
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: finanzen]

Comment: very good solution as the element_to_be_clickable makes the code much faster